# Jquery on click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code that opens an accordeon on hover but i need to make it work each tab on click instead, i've tried to change the "hover" to "click" but no success, could someone here please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(function() {
    $('#accordion > li').hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
    });
});
```

the idea from Tushar Gupta is the only one that's partially working, it opens the accordeon on click, but if the user clicks another tab while one is open there's a bug...

i make a fiddle with the whole code.

http://jsfiddle.net/C8Kp8/ <-- Tushar Gupta's solution

http://jsfiddle.net/SHmuc/ <-- Original Code

thank you all for your help, its really appreciated.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle for better understanding... ??

Comment: your logic using animate seems falling, you should use the callback of each animation or a promise or animate it using toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this. @Alex's answer is good but ignores the first click, and doesn't close the open elements when a closed element is clicked. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SHmuc/5/). In this version, the `more` links in the accordion elements also work.

```
$(function() {
     $('#accordion li').click(function() {
         var $this = $(this);

         if (!$this.hasClass('open')) {
             // open clicked accordion element
             $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
             $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
             $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
             $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();

             // close other open accordion element
             $("#accordion li.open").stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
             $("#accordion li.open .heading").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
             $("#accordion li.open .description, #accordion li.open .bgDescription").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
             $("#accordion li.open").removeClass("open");
             $this.addClass('open');
         }
         else {
             // close this accordion element
             $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
             $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
             $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
             $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
             $this.removeClass('open');
         }
     });

     $('#accordion > li a').click(function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or this

```
    $(function() {
    $('#accordion > li').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
            $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
            $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
            $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
            $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
            $this.removeClass('open');
        }
        else {
            $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
            $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
            $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
            $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
            $this.addClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean toggle event instead: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/  anyway, this has been removed from jquery

Comment: My bad, ya using toggle instead of animating using fade/slide, sorry

Comment: Although it makes perfect sense, with this code the slider/accordeon wont open any tab.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. I fixed it so the 'more' links work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this matter, the problem is when you click another "tab" it wont close the one that is open in the first place, lets say i click "tab A" then when i click "tab C" both stay open.

Comment: that is another question actually, but just add a line of code which animates all lis but not the clicked one